# Define and access virtual properties in cakePHP - where and how?

Tags: cakephp

In an application a lecture hasMany slides and a slide belongsTo a lecture. When the index function of lecture is called we would like to add a column which displays the amount off slides belonging to a certain lecture.

I tried to define this as as a $virtualFields in the lecture model like this:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'slides_amount' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `eflux`.`slides` AS `Slide` LEFT JOIN `eflux`.`lectures` 
            AS `Lecture` ON (`Slide`.`lecture_id` = `Lecture`.`id`) 
                WHERE lecture_id = \''.$id.'\'')';
```

The problem is that I am not able to access the current $id of the object and therefore MySQL returns an error.

My next try was to use the controller for this:

```
$lectures = $this->Lecture->findByCourseId($course_id);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($lectures); $i++) {
   $slide_amount = $this->Lecture->Slide->find('count', array('conditions' => 'lecture_id = \' '.$id.'\''));
   $slide_amounts[$i] = $slide_amount;
}
```

I was also not able to access the id of the current $lecture-object to determin the amount of slides belonging to that lecture.

Finally I did it in the view:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($slides_helper); $i++) {
            if ($slides_helper[$i]['slides']['lecture_id'] == $lecture['Lecture']['id']) {
                echo $slides_helper[$i][0]['count'];
            }   

    }?>
```

Only here I could acces the id of the current object or the $lectures array. But I feel that the view is not the place to handle this.

What is best practice to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller, you can try:

```
$lectures = $this->Lecture->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Lecture.course_id'=>$course_id)));

foreach ($lectures as &$lecture){
   $lecture['Lecture']['slide_count'] = count($lecture['Slide']);
}
$this->set('lectures', $lectures);
```

and then access the count in your view with

```
foreach ($lectures as $lecture){
    echo $lecture['Lecture']['slide_count'];
}
```

The code might not be exact... you can help us give more accurate code by pasting the results of the following code:

Place this in your controller:

```
$lectures = $this->Lecture->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Lecture.course_id'=>$course_id)));
pr($lectures);
```

EDIT FOR PAGINATION:

Something like this might work for your pagination

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = array('Lecture.course_id'=>$course_id);
$this->paginate['limit'] = '10';

$lectures = $this->paginate('Lecture');

//PERFORM THE LOOP TO ADD SLIDE COUNT

$this->set('lectures', $lectures);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your code was - respite my sloppy question - very exact. I figured that the array was changed by the foreach-loop but I used 

`$this->set('lectures',  $this->paginate());`

instead of:
`$this->set('lectures',  $lectures);`

Which caused that the modified $lectures was not properly passed (?). Maybe someone can give me a hint for that to improve my understanding and the further proper use of the paginate() function.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Additionally I had to define the deafult query conditions in the controller as `public $paginate = array(...)` to avoid `Indirect modification of overloaded property LecturesController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\LecturesController.php, line 28]`